# google cloud messaging checking api key validity where to run the command curl?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, api-key

I'm following the documentation of google cloud messaging [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) on how to check the validity of my api key.
This is what it says:

"run this command:"

```
# api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

but I don't know where to run that command. Definitely it isn't in the command line because `api_key` is not recognized. I need to check the validity of my api key because I keep getting status 401 response in sending message from server. I'm trying to get to work the sample [here.](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run it from the command line, just run the `curl` part, replacing the `$api_key` with your actual GCM Api key. Make sure you remove the hash as well, otherwise it will be interpreted as a comment and won't be executed.

Anyway I think is better to make this kind of requests using tools such as [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).